# How to upload plugins in wordpress on docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker, plugins

I am running the latest [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) mac app and have created a new `docker-compose.yml` in my project directory. (which is my wordpress theme).

[image]

This is my `docker-compose.yml` config file below, following the steps from their https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

I've also added some params to the wordpress block to keep my database persistent so I don't loose my database when I `docker-compose up -d`

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

But I'm having troubles working out how to upload plugins as it's asking me for FTP credentials.

[image]

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your having trouble with WordPress plugins directory perms. 
Go inside of this container and chmod -r 755 ./plugins. 
Also check the owner of the directory. And change it to www-data.

Comment: Ok so I tried this but still adding asking for FTP credentials when uploading plugin. See my terminal here  https://i.imgur.com/yugOvUs.png

Comment: goto wp-content and just paste this. chmod -R 755 ./plugins && chown -R www-data:www-data .

Comment: Actually just got it working by running `chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content` after exec into the container

Comment: Yap. It was exactly what I said in the first comment :) . I'm glad you got it solved.

Comment: Yep you called it! Cheers